# Issues with REST-API in parse after migrating to Parse-Server

Tags: rest, ubuntu, parse-platform, debian, digital-ocean

I am trying to migrate the Parse-server to a Debian Server and I am running into some trouble with the REST-API. When I try to call my application's login-function I receive the following error: `Cannot POST /parse/login`.

These are the steps I have followed successfully before I received a server error.

1. Installed Parse-Server in Debian
2. Installed the cloud code and added my code to the file `main.js`.
3. My cloud code contains a login-function and I had a successful call with `curl -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <id1>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}' 'serverName/parse/functions/login'`.
4. The final step was to call the REST-API which gave me a `Cannot POST /parse/login` error. I called it with `curl -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <id1>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}' 'serverName/parse/login'`

[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-3-%E2%80%93-install-and-configure-parse-server-and-pm2) is the migration guide I have followed
[This](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/) is the REST-API guide I have followed.

Can someone help me with this server error?

Comment: this question lacks a lot of info. Can you add some details about the app? Is it self programmed? If yes, what is the application server?

Comment: I have now edited the question, it is more about the REST-API than the actual application.

Comment: The `-d '{}'`part of your curl statement forces POST. Remove it and you'll be using GET as per the answers below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Login requires the `GET` method not `POST`!

By doing a simple `GET` to that `URL`, you should then be presented with the below error.  Obviously you need to pass your params to make it successful.

```
 {
        "code": 200,
        "error": "username is required."
    }
```

Removing the `-d '{}'` will revert that `curl` to a `GET`

Answer (score 1):

This answer is the best shot I can do with the information provided. The problem is most likely that the application is expecting a `GET` request (or some other HTTP method other than `POST`) but your curl request sends a `POST` request.

To see what `curl` is sending you can add `-v` (I put in `example.com` just to have a server which responds)

```
$ curl -v -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <id1>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}' 'example.com/serverName/parse/login'
*   Trying 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946) port 80 (#0)
> POST /serverName/parse/login HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> X-Parse-Application-Id: <id1>
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 2
```

The [login function in the API guide](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#logging-in) expects a `GET` request:

> To do this, send a GET request to the /1/login endpoint with username and password as URL-encoded parameters:

I assume with the migration you also upgrade to a newer `parse.com` app and the older version accepted `POST` and the newer one not.

You'll need to change your curl request to use `GET` instead of `POST`. Just follow [the example provided](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#logging-in). Remove the `-d` parameter and add the `--data-urlencode` parameters